# Increasing tap radius of bing maps pushpin?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a custom pushpin that I use to display information on the map when it is tapped.
However, it is rather tough to tap exactly on the pushpin (I can't increase the size of the pushpin anymore, It would look very ugly)

Is there a way to increase the tap radius of the pushpin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Depechie, but here is something that works for what you need. You can change the ControlTemplate of the pin to match what you need. Here is the existing Template for the Bing Maps PushPin but with a huge margin.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate1" TargetType="Maps:Pushpin">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Margin="100" Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="31" MinWidth="29">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="4"/>
            </Grid>
            <Polygon Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Points="0,0 29,0 0,29" Width="29" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then you just need to use that template

```
    <Maps:Pushpin Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplate1}"/>
```

You'll want to play with the position of the pin so that it actually points to the proper location.

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try. I'm actually transforming the size of the shape based on the zoomlevel, but I can probably apply that transform to the contentGrid as well.

Comment: Make sure you set the Background to Transparent

Answer (score 0):

I would guess fire up Photoshop and create more transparant image content around the pushpin...
But be sure to check the position of the pushpin again, because if the width and height changes, the midpoint changes.

Comment: I cant use a static image. I'm using a shape, which I colorize dynamically.

Comment: Ok than it won't work :( maybe you could wrap them inside a rectangle, but that would seem overkill... sorry no idea about shapes.